# Describe the language accepted by the DFA in set notation.

Tags: formal-languages, automata, computational-mathematics

I want to find the language accepted by the DFA and explain it in set notation. For example: L={w|every odd position of w is a b}. That would be an example of a language accepted by a DFA in set notation. The regular expression I got for my DFA is the following:

q1 = q4(01)

q2 = q1(1) + q3(0)

q3 = q2(01)

q4 = q1(0) + q3(1)

After substituting q1 and q3 in q4 equation

q4 = q4(01)(0) + q2(01)(1)

Im not sure if I did the regular expression correctly. But I attempted to do it to get a sense of how to explain the DFA in english. From the DFA all I understand is that the accepted strings I've found have all had odd length for example(0,000,111,00111) these strings are all accepted by the DFA. But there are strings that have odd length but not accepted like "01011"

The DFA image is below

[DFA IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRHls.png)

Comment: You need to read what a regular expression is and what a regular grammar is. You're mixing the two.

Comment: Are you asking how to write it as a regular expression, or how to describe the language in English? Or some combination of the two? The DFA recognizes odd-length strings with an even number of $1$s in odd positions, but I don't know if that English sentence is formal enough for your use case.

Comment: Yeah basically just explaining it in english. I was trying to use a regular expression to try to make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Sigma := ( 0 | 1 )$.
The regex is $$ (0 |  1\Sigma (0 \Sigma)^* 1) ( \Sigma 0 | \Sigma 1 \Sigma (0 \Sigma)^* 1)^* $$